# How to after upload redirect to `/summary/1/` (/summary/saved object id/)

Tags: django

```
def upload(request):
        user = request.user
        upload_form = UploadForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if request.method == "POST":
                if upload_form.is_valid():
                        my_model = upload_form.save(commit=False)
                        my_model.user = user
                        print my_model.src
                        my_model.save()
                        return render_to_response('index.html',, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

        return render_to_response('index.html', {'upload_form': upload_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How to after upload redirect to `/summary/1/` (/summary/saved object id/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/summary/'+id)
```

and the nicer variant would be

```
return HttpResonseRedirect('/summary/%i/' % id)
```

and the nicest variant is (so that you dont have to hardcode your urls in your view)

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(yourViewNameHere, args=[id]))
```

if you wanted to use

```
reversed_url = reverse(yourViewNameHere, kwargs = {'id':id})
return HttpResponseRedirect(reversed_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

import

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
```

then

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/summary/%s/' %object_id)
```